# while using local external library in maven, it throws SurefireBooterForkException error

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have created jar of maven project, which contains 2 packages and many different classes.
Then, I copied the jar file into another project folder and added dependency as below

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/test_project.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

also added additionalClasspathElements within surefire plugin as below

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>
                            ${project.basedir}/lib/test_project.jar
                        </additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
```

Now, when I try to extend/inherit any class from the jar file, I am able to see all my methods but when I try to run command **mvn test** it throws SurefireBooterForkException as below

[image]

Can someone please help me in resolving above error?

Comment: It would have been simpler to `mvn install` the first project (installed the jar into the local cache) and using the installed jar as a dependency without using system scope...

Comment: I already tried but it still shows the same error